# including other templates

Tags: templates, playframework-2.0

I have the following situation.

My project has a "main.scala.html" file and a folder called "dashboard".
In this dashboard folder is a "index.scala.html" file, which **works well** with including inside the main file (@content) with the following syntax:

```
@main("index.title"){
    <h3>test of dashboard index content</h3>
}
```

So, my specific question is now, I want to call another "sub template" inside this "dashboard/index.scala.html" file?! e.g. the sub-template is called "dashboard/detail.scala.html". How is the syntax I must declare in this "detail" sub-template and how do I have to call this sub-template inside the index page of the dashboard folder?

I looked up the wiki https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaTemplateUseCases but I didn't found a working solution for me, maybe I have some misunderstandings.

I'm looking forward to your answers, thank you very much!

Cheers,

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call it as you would call any other function or template from your controller. There is an example in the documentation

> ## Home
>
> @common.sideBar()

Comment: OK, cool. And if I don't have a sideBar ? What's the point between sideBar and the previous content of the question/documentation ?